# yii, CactiveForm checkboxlist

Tags: php, validation, yii, checkboxlist, yii-cformmodel

im really trying to render a checkboxlist, never did make a try on it before so im having problems with it, im trying to render all the checkboxes foreach column or attribute made, this is the action controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Parametro;

        $variable = file_get_contents('protected\column.txt');
        $vars = explode(' ', $variable);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Parametro']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Parametro'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
            'variable'=>$vars,
        ));
    }
```

this is the model with another some methods

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    $variable = file_get_contents('protected\column.txt');
    return array(
        array('parametro_id', 'required'),
        array('parametro_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, parametro_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        array($variable, 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),   
    );
}
public function generateAttributeLabel($variable = null)
{
    if($variable)
    {
        $variable = file_get_contents('protected\column.txt');
    }
    return $variable;
}   

public function attributeLabels()
{
        return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'parametro_id' => 'Parametro',
    );
}
```

the form where im trying to make the checkboxlist

```
<div>
        <?php echo $form->checkboxList($model, $variable, array(0 => 1)); ?>
</div>
```

and the content of the file if you ask

```
lololo trying
```

the are some columns that are being generated automatically and im storing their names on this file separated by spaces, everything seems to be fine until i got to the checkboxlist on form, it gives me error like strpos() or something, how can i make this checkbox to render and to save 1 data to thoses who are checked by specific columns?

Comment: what is your exact problem? are you not able to get the checkboxes?

Comment: no, i cant, i get strpos() error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that you are no able to get the check boxes then try this


### Update

In your **_form.php**

```
 <div>
            <?php echo CHtml::checkBoxList('createCheck', array(), $variable); ?>
    </div>
```

you need to change your **controller action** for that

```
public function actionCreate()
        {
            $model=new Parametro;

            $variable = file_get_contents('protected\column.txt');
            $vars = explode(' ', $variable);
          // make SURE that you are getting $vars as array
          if(isset($_POST['Parametro']))
            {
                $model->attributes=$_POST['Parametro'];
                if(isset($_POST['createCheck']))
            {
                 $newVar=array();
                $checkVariables=$_POST['createCheck'];
                foreach($checkVariables as $key)
                {
                    $newVar[]=$vars[$key];
                }
                if(!empty($newVar))
                {

                    foreach($newVar as $saveIt)
                    {

                        $model->$saveIt='y';
                    }
                     $model->save();
                }    

               }
               $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
            }

            $this->render('create',array(
                'model'=>$model,
                'variable'=>$vars,
            ));
        }
```

**Note:-** it might throw you some errors as i do not know your table structure. If you get any problem try to solve it  or just ask

Comment: it did work, but its not saving data to its specific column, like if 'lololo' if checked, then it should save a 1 or y to 'lololo' column, now i have that problem

Comment: please help me, im new at this, im sorry for asking too much, im very curious about the process

Comment: In your **$vars**  array, are the values representing the names of the columns?

Comment: Updated my answer. You can try it now

Comment: now its not saving in the db but its redirecting back to index, if you did not know about the structure of the table, id and parametro_id are the only one int(10), the rest are being created as tinyint(1) NULL

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44032/discussion-between-let-me-see-and-nosthertus)